# Mysql Database Error #1044

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

How to create a database in Mysql?
My Problem:
 #1044 - Access denied for user 'u3274251_eg'@'localhost' to database 'mydbname'. 
Screenshot:
http://gbhost.bugs3.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/IMG_20160223_091226_258.jpg
Please help me.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add permissions for u3274251_eg'@'localhost.  Log in via phpMyAdmin and add the permission for create database there.

Comment: Log in as the superuser or any user that has all priveleges in phpmyadmin. Go to the **Users** tab and hit `Edit Priveleges` to the user 'u3274251_eg'. Choose anything you want that the user can control.